# Calculate Employee Timesheet Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose you have a timeclock table with only a timestamp entry for each timeclock event:

```
Userid  CheckTime
312     2018-05-08 05:52:00
312     2018-05-08 18:06:00
312     2018-05-10 05:55:00
312     2018-05-10 18:00:00
312     2018-05-11 05:58:00
312     2018-05-11 18:00:00
312     2018-05-12 05:35:00
312     2018-05-12 18:00:00
```

How can I tally the events in SQL Server to show like this?

```
Day       Date       In      Out        Reg      OT
Tuesday   5/8/2018   5:52AM  6:06PM     12.00    0.00
Thursday  5/10/2018  5:55AM  6:00PM     12.00    0.00
Friday    5/11/2018  5:58AM  6:00PM     12.00    0.00
Saturday  5/12/2018  5:35AM  6:00PM     12.00    0.42
```

Plus, we have overnight people who start their shift in one day and carry over to another day.

I'm not sure how to calculate this since it is row based vs column based.

I've tried this...but it doesn't work correctly...

```
         ;WITH emp
                 AS (SELECT [UserID],
                            [CheckTime],
                    CAST([CheckTime] AS DATE) AS [Day],
                    Row_Number()
                    OVER( PARTITION BY [UserID], CAST([CheckTime] AS DATE)
                     ORDER BY [UserID], [CheckTime]) AS [RowNumber]
                     FROM   [dbo].[Clock_Data] WHERE CHECKTIME 
                     BETWEEN '2018-05-06' AND '2018-05-13')
            SELECT 
             t1.[UserID], 
             E.[Last Name]AS [EMPID],
                   MIN(t1.[CheckTime]) AS [time_in],
                   MAX(t2.[CheckTime]) AS [time_out],
                   CAST((SUM(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(ss,  t1.[CheckTime], 
            t2.[CheckTime]) , 0)) / 3600)-1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' +
            FROM   emp AS t1
                   LEFT JOIN emp AS t2
                          ON ( t1.[UserID] = t2.[UserID]
                               AND t1.[Day] = t2.[Day]
                               AND t1.[RowNumber] = ( t2.[RowNumber] - 1 )
                               AND t2.[RowNumber] % 2 = 0 
                               )
                    INNER JOIN Employees as E on t1.Userid = E.[ID Number]
            GROUP  BY t1.[UserID], E.[Last Name]
            ORDER  BY t1.[UserID]
```

Comment: This sort of query is much more complex than it seems on the surface and any query we give you would require equal understanding of it in order to maintain it. Things to consider: missed punches, accidental double punches and throttling to avoid that, punches that cross day boundaries and as a result duration calculations during daylight savings transitions for the clock locations that observe that depending on whether they sync their time from the server or not, domain specific business logic for overtime vs regular hours calculations, etc.

Comment: I'd suggest breaking this into several smaller chunks with functions and views leveraging those functions and then building up a more manageable query or procedure from there. Something to get throttled distinct punches, something to fill in missing punches after that, something to categorize punches as in or out on top of that, something to account for daylight savings after that, something to include your business logic for rate calculations after that, etc and then a view or procedure to consume all of that. And remember this might need to be rerun if the data is retroactively modified.

Comment: Understood. This is actually maintained by a timeclock system. The timeclock data is pulled out which will ensure a clock in/clock out state. No double punches.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments above there are a LOT of complexities in this type of query. Missed/duplicate punches. Daylight saving time. Holidays, weekends. The types of things that might count as O/T for whatever rules you need. But for a nice clean set of data like you have you can do this fairly easily. This is by no means a complete solution because you have a LOT of things to iron out for details. But this should serve as a decent starting point.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Userid int
    , CheckTime datetime
)

insert @Something values
    (312, '2018-05-08 05:52:00')
    , (312, '2018-05-08 18:06:00')
    , (312, '2018-05-10 05:55:00')
    , (312, '2018-05-10 18:00:00')
    , (312, '2018-05-11 05:58:00')
    , (312, '2018-05-11 18:00:00')
    , (312, '2018-05-12 05:35:00')
    , (312, '2018-05-12 18:00:00');

with OrderedResults as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Userid order by CheckTime)
    from @Something
)
, InPunch as
(
    select *
        , GroupNum = Row_Number () over(partition by Userid order by RowNum)
    from OrderedResults
    where RowNum % 2 = 1
)
, OutPunch as 
(
    select *
        , GroupNum = Row_Number () over(partition by Userid order by RowNum)
    from OrderedResults
    where RowNum % 2 = 0
)

select ip.Userid
    , PunchDate = convert(date, ip.CheckTime)
    , CheckIn = ip.CheckTime
    , CheckOut = op.CheckTime
from InPunch ip
join OutPunch op on op.GroupNum = ip.GroupNum
```

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure this is a good starting point...Userid PunchDate  
`code ID     PunchDate    CheckIn         CheckOut
 1 2012-04-25 2012-04-25 12:05:00 2012-04-25 13:02:00
 1 2012-04-25 2012-04-25 12:05:00 2012-04-26 12:03:00
 1 2012-04-25 2012-04-25 12:05:00 2012-04-25 14:22:00
    1 2012-04-25 2012-04-25 12:05:00 2012-04-26 17:09:00`

Comment: @EdwardRhoades - Comments are not good for formatting and not sure what you are data is trying to show. I am curious why you think this isn't a good starting point. It returns the rows of data just like the OP asked for. I just didn't include the DATEDIFF parts.